# Extracting values from text file

Tags: python

I have one text file as follows with 2 columns

```
44333373    -5.829738285
3007762     -5.468521083
16756295    -5.247183569
46197456    -5.216096421
46884567    -5.195179321
44333390    -5.162411562
44420579    -5.133122186
6439190     -5.028260409
...
```

I want to extract values which greater than -5.162411562 ideal output should look like

Output

```
44333373    -5.829738285
3007762     -5.468521083
16756295    -5.247183569
46197456    -5.216096421
46884567    -5.195179321
```

To accomplish this task i wrote simple python script

```
f1=open("file.txt","r")
n=0
for line in f1.readlines():
     if float(n) > -5.162411562:
        print line
```

But it is just reading all data in file. I know it is a very simple task but I am not able to figure out where I am going wrong. Can anybody help?

Comment: One more thing: your example output doesn't show lines with values greater than -5.162411562, it shows lines with values *less than* -5.162411562. They're negative. You will need to write `<` instead of `>` in the code in either of the answers below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with the code you have presented is that the value of `n` is never changes, so the `if` statement will always evaluate to `True`, and therefore the `line` will be printed:

```
f1=open("file.txt","r")
n=0  # the `n` is set here
for line in f1.readlines():
     if float(n) > -5.162411562:  # `n` is always `0`, so this is always `True`
        print line
```

You'll want to update the variable `n` with the number extracted from the second column of each line.

Furthermore, the `if` condition will have to have its comparison operator changed from `>` (greater than) to `<` (less than), as the values you show in your output are values which are "less than -5.162411562", not "greater than"

Also, it should be noted that the `n=0` is not necessarily required.

With those changes, we get the following code:

```
f1 = open("file.txt","r")
for line in f1.readlines():
  n = line.split()[1]          # get the second column
  if float(n) < -5.162411562:  # changed the direction comparison
     print line.rstrip()       # remove the newline from the line read
                               # from the file to prevent doubling of newlines
                               # from the print statement
f1.close()                     # for completeness, close the file
```

The resulting output is:

```
44333373        -5.829738285
3007762         -5.468521083
16756295        -5.247183569
46197456        -5.216096421
46884567        -5.195179321
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you need to actually set `n` to a value aside from zero. How about:

```
with open('file.txt') as f1:
  for line in f1: # readlines is not necessary here
    n = float(line.split()[1]) # line.split()[0] is the first number
    if n > -5.162411562:
        print (line.rstrip('\r\n')) # rstrip to remove the existing EOL in line
```

Answer (score 0):

`line` contains `44333373    -5.829738285`. when looping through `lines` you need to split the line & consider the first element & you dont need `n`. Then compare. So the code changes to -

```
f1=open("file.txt","r")
for line in f1.readlines():
     if float(line.split()[1]) > -5.162411562:
        print line
```

Slight modification here. `readlines` reads the entire file contents into memory in one single go. If the file is too big then you could have problems. The file operator in python is a iterator. how cool is that! Also `open` by default opens a file in `read` mode. So the code further simplifies to -

```
for line in open('file.txt'):
    if float(line.split()[1]) > -5.162411562:
        print line
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Note that one should also close the file, and probably remove `n=0`. Also, the call to `readlines` makes this program unnecessarily allocate memory of the file's size, which can be significant.

Comment: The updated version actually makes it impossible to ever close the file; you may be leaking the descriptor (although some Python implementations free it once the file is no longer reachable).

Comment: that's what mostly happens. python will take care of closing once the file is no longer used or reachable. I believe it closes the file descriptors once a function exit happens.

Comment: **cpython** indeed exhibits this behavior. However, many other implementations [don't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404430/does-filehandle-get-closed-automatically-in-python-after-it-goes-out-of-scope/2404671#2404671).