# python, will opened file be closed?

Tags: python, python-2.7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does filehandle get closed automatically in Python after it goes out of scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404430/does-filehandle-get-closed-automatically-in-python-after-it-goes-out-of-scope)

I am new to python.  i know if you open a file and write it, you need to close it at the end.

```
in_file = open(from_file)
indata = in_file.read()

out_file = open(to_file, 'w')
out_file.write(indata)

out_file.close()
in_file.close()
```

if I write my code this way.

```
open(to_file, 'w').write(open(from_file).read())
```

I cannot really close it, will it be automatically closed?

Answer (score 8):

It will *eventually* be closed, but there is no guarantee as to when. The best way to do this when you need to handle such things is a [`with`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) statement:

```
with open(from_file) as in_file, open(to_file, "w") as out_file:
    out_file.write(in_file.read())

# Both files are guaranteed to be closed here.
```

See also: http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example

Answer (score 6):

The Python garbage collector will close the file automatically for you when it destroys the file object, but you don't have a lot of control over when that actually happens (thus, the bigger problem is that you won't know if an error / exception happens during the file close)

The [preferred way to do this after Python 2.5](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) is with the `with` structure:

```
with open("example.txt", 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
```

And the file is **guaranteed** to be closed for you after you are done with it, regardless of what happens.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://pypy.org/compat.html, CPython will close the file; however PyPy will close the file only when garbage collector runs. So for compatibility and style reasons it is better to close the file explicitly (or using `with` construct)

Comment: to be precise, when GC runs or interpreter exits. CPython will never close the file that's in a GC cycles.