# Finding strings in Text Files in Python

Tags: python, regex

I need a program to find a string (S) in a file (P), and return the number of thimes it appears in the file, to do this i decided tocreate a function:

```
def file_reading(P, S):
  file1= open(P, 'r')
  pattern = S
  match1 = "re.findall(pattern, P)"
    if match1 != None:
      print (pattern)
```

I know it doesn't look very good, but for some reason it's not outputing anything, let alone the right answer.

Comment: Why are you encapsulating your `re.findall()` call in quotation marks? And not using your input file?

Comment: Fix your indentation. Badly indented Python code is nonsense.

Comment: You never actually read the file.

Comment: That's the way i was taught to do it, Is that not right?

Comment: No. Your function isn't going to get called if it's a string. You are misremembering what you were taught.

Comment: Please, give us more info i.e. sample of file content and pattern that you are using.

Comment: @j.evans please do not approve edits that drastically change how the code in your question performs. If you desire to make such changes please add them as an [edit] to the question so the necessary context for existing answers/comments is not lost.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your code.

First of all, calling [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) returns a file object. It does not read the contents of the file. For that you need to use `read()` or iterate through the file object.

Secondly, if your goal is to count the number of matches of a string, you don't need regular expressions. You can use the string function `count()`. Even still, it doesn't make sense to put the regular expression call in quotes.

```
match1 = "re.findall(pattern, file1.read())"
```

Assigns the string `"re.findall(pattern, file1.read())"` to the variable `match1`.

Here is a version that should work for you:

```
def file_reading(file_name, search_string):
    # this will put the contents of the file into a string
    file1 = open(file_name, 'r')
    file_contents = file1.read()
    file1.close()  # close the file

    # return the number of times the string was found
    return file_contents.count(search_string)
```

Comment: for GodOrWhoeverIsInChargeOrNot's sake, __close that file__ !

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I made an update based on your suggestion- I agree it's better to be explicit, but my understanding was that the file object would close when it goes out of scope: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404430/does-filehandle-get-closed-automatically-in-python-after-it-goes-out-of-scope **EDIT**: I take that back, I just read the second answer which explains the case when exceptions are raised.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few errors; let's go through them one by one:

1. Anything in quotes is a string.  Putting `"re.findall(pattern, file1.read())"` in quotes just makes a string.  If you actually want to call the re.findall function, no quotes are needed :)
2. You check whether `match1` is None or not, which is really great, but then you should return that matches, not the initial pattern.
3. The if-statement should not be indented.

Also:

- Always a close a file once you have opened it!  Since most people forget to do this, it is better to use the `with open(filename, action)` [syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31334226/9222529).

So, taken together, it would look like this (I've changed some variable names for clarity):

```
def file_reading(input_file, pattern):
    with open(input_file, 'r') as text_file:
        data = text_file.read()
        matches = re.findall(pattern, data)

        if matches:
            print(matches)  # prints a list of all strings found
```

Comment: The pythonic way to test against `None` is using identity testing, ie `if matches is not None:` (`None` is garanteed to be a singleton). But since `re.findall()` returns an empty list if nothing matches, the correct test here is a plain `if matches:`

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers thanks for pointing that out!  This is my first time editing an answer based on feedback.  Should I edit the code or add a note at the end?

Answer (score 0):

You can read line by line instead of reading the entire file and find the nunber of time the pattern is repeated and add it to the total count `c`

```
def file_reading(file_name, pattern):
  c = 0
  with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
      c + = line.count(pattern)
  if c: print c
```